# How does 68% of data lies in 1 standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have 20 Score values:

1, 3, 4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 19, 23, 32, 34, 38, 43, 48, 53, 59, 63, 69, 74, 85.

So, I calculate the Standard Deviation using:

$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum(x-\bar x)^2}n} $$

.. which is 25.4.

Now, from 68-95-99.7% rule there are 68% i.e. at least 13 values from these points would be within 1 Standard deviation?

Is that correct? Then, what are those values? In other words, how many values are in 1 standard deviation and 2 standard deviation?

Comment: Your Question omits mention of the *mean*, e.g. points "within 1 Standard deviation'' of the mean.

Comment: Calculating the mean as $34.7$, you have $12$ values within $1$ standard deviation of the mean, and all $20$ values within $2$ standard deviations. You would need more values (say $200$) to get closer to $68 \%$ and $95 \%$, since the normal distribution is a continuous distribution.

Comment: @TobyMak: How do you calculate or know there are 12 values?

Comment: One standard deviation is from $34.7-25.4$ to $34.7+25.4$, two standard deviations is from $34.7 - 2 \times 25.4$ to $34.7 + 2 \times 25.4$.

Comment: Thanks @TobyMak. Do you suggest that I should delete this question or will you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the mean as $ 34.7$, you have $12$ values within $1$ standard deviation of the mean, and all $20$ values within $2$ standard deviations.

One standard deviation is from $34.7−25.4$ to $34.7+25.4$, two standard deviations is from $34.7−2 \times 25.4$ to $34.7+2\times25.4$.

You would need more values (say $200$) to get closer to $68 \%$ and $95 \%$, since the normal distribution is a continuous distribution.